# Alert box shows form data when clicking button

Tags: javascript, onclick, alert

I am looking to create a button at the bottom of a form that will create an alert box that will show the form data entered. Form includes:
First Name
Last Name
Address 1
Address 2
City
State
Zip
Phone
Fax

Once the form is completed, the button is clicked and an alert box pops up showing the form data entered.

Does anyone know how to accomplish without the form actually being submitted or validated? There is no database for the form data to be submitted to, so there is no database to pull the information from.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have not included the form code due to its length, but the current code I am working with for the Alert Box looks like this:

```
 <script>
 function display_alert()
 {
 alert("");
 }
 </script>

 <body>
 <input type="button" onclick="display_alert()" value="Display alert box">
 </body>
```

Comment: Are you using any java script library like jQuery?

Comment: If the form shouldnt get submitted, then you need to return false , from your onclick event of your submit button. as far as displaying the form data in a modal dialog is concerned, you can do it programitically only. i dont think so you will find any difficult in doing the this .

Comment: @Lekhnath: I beleive you should pay attention to the tags and understand the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I get it right you need something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById('send').onclick = function(e){
       alert(document.getElementById("name").value);
       return false;
   }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="send" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't really get what you mean with a database to pull the information from, but the example uses a click event to get the data from the form field and shows it in an alert without a submit.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, but using this function, how do you display more than one field in the Alert Box?

Comment: Just add input fields like the name field and alert them with their id like the example.

Answer (score 1):

html code:

```
<html>
<SCRIPT SRC="PR8_4.JS"></SCRIPT>
<body>
<form name=details>
<table>
 <tr><td>ENTER  FRIST NAME:<input type=text  name=fname></td></tr>
 <tr><td>ENTER  LAST  NAME:<input type=text  name=lname></td></tr>
 <tr><td>ENTER  PHONE NUM :<input type=text  name=phnum></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="display();">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript code:

```
function display()
{
var x=document.details.fname.value;
var y=document.details.lname.value;
var z=document.details.phnum.value;
alert("FIRST NAME:"+x+"     "+"LAST NAME:"+y+"     "+"PHONE NUMBER:"+z);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for your contribution. Can you edit to explain how your answer differs from the existing answers here?

Comment: ultimately all the codes here are written to produce the same output...but i thought my answer was easy to understand (specially in case of the beginners), so i posted it.       ps-i thought i kept it simple...thatz  how i think it differs by the rest..

Answer (score 0):

To stop a form submitting you can create an onsubmit event within the  tag and return false - e.g. ...form elements.... This has the benefit of working when someone submits the form by pressing the enter key as well as pressing the submit button.

Thus, to achieve what you desire you could create a function (lets call it formAlert) and call it from the onsubmit event e.g. ...form elements...

The formAlert function would look something like:

```
function formAlert() {
    alert_string = '';
    alert_string = alert_string + document.getElementById('first_name').value;
    alert_string = alert_string + ' ';
    alert_string = alert_string + document.getElementById('last_name').value;

    alert(alert_string);
}
```

and this would correspond to a form looking like:

```
<form id="foo" onsubmit="formAlert(); return false;">
    <p><label for="first_name">First Name<label><input type="text" id="first_name" value="fred" /></p>
    <p><label for="last_name">Last Name<label><input type="text" id="last_name" value="blogs" /></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="click me" /></p>
</form>
```

Note1, this won't be a pretty modal box - it'll simply display "fred blogs" in a Javascript alert box.

Note2, if there is a Javascript error your form will still submit (although in the example here it'll submit to itself).

Here is a JS Fiddle demonstrating the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/D59su/

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="javascriptform.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form name= "details"><div class="box1"><div id="a"><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="LAST NAME"></div><br>
                      <div id="b"><input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="FIRST NAME"></div><br>
                      <div id="c"><input type="e-mail" name="email" placeholder="E-MAIL"></div><br>
                      <div id="d"><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="PASSWORD"></div><br>
                      <div id="sub-button"><button onclick="getdetails();">submit</button></div></form>

    </div>

    <script>
        function getdetails()
        {
var a = document.forms["details"]["lastname"].value;
var b = document.forms["details"]["firstname"].value;
var c= document.forms["details"]["email"].value;

alert("Your name is "+a+" "+b+". Your e-mail is "+c);

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It Is Very Simple

Using `.value` will help.

**HTML**:

`<form onsubmit="return myFunction()>`
`<input type="text" id="name>`
`<input type="submit" value="SEND">`

> Use **return** before your function

**Javascript**:

`function myFunction () {var name = document.getElementById("name").value; alert("Hi " + name)}`

After Submitting It Will Show As (If I Write Alex and Submit It)

Hi Alex

Hope it will work